# PDFのブックマークと注釈のエキスポート

Tags: pdf, vba, console, annotations

PDFのブックマーク（Bookmark）と注釈（Annotation）を一覧で出す方法はありますか？
できればシステムチェックにエクスポートしたい。例えばVBA、またはコマンド行、あるいはScript。サードパーティのライブラリーを使っても構いません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

フリーのコマンドラインツールがあるようです。

https://www.pdflabs.com/blog/export-and-import-pdf-bookmarks/